# Angular 2 check if child component is ready

Tags: angular

Is it possible to check in root component `AppComponent` that it's child component is ready. Child component is a component that is loaded using routes and `<router-outlet>` directive in AppComponent template. The child's component route has an async authentication guard `canActivate`. I want to execute some code in AppComponent when the authentication guard is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a service. Register a service in the `providers` of the AppComponent NgModule (or directly on the AppComponent). The service can have an EventEmitter or Subject which the AppComponent subscribes to. When the authentication guard is complete, it emits an event on the service,

Comment: The problem is that I have many children components and some of them has guards, some of them has no guards. It would be much easier if I will not change guards or children components. I want to change only AppComponent

Comment: I suppose you could make all of your child components extend a BaseComponent class, which raises an event on the service in a `ngOnInit` method. The only problem with this is that you'd have to be careful that any child component which also has an ngOnInit remembers to call `super.ngOnInit()'

Answer (score 0):

See [component communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html), for example *Parent listens for child event*

Comment: That section of the article refers to binding to an EventEmitter on the child component - that applies to direct child components, it can't be done with routed compontents.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my UserService.

```ts
import { Injectable, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class UserService
{
  id: number;
  userEmail: string;
  userName: string;
  gravatar:
  {
    md5: string
    ,defaultAva: string
  };

  loggedIn = false;
  private initUser: Promise<void>;

  constructor
  (
    private http: Http
    ,private router: Router
    ,private route: ActivatedRoute
    ,private applicationRef: ApplicationRef
  )
  {
    this.initUser = this.login();
  }

  login()
  {
    return this.http
    .get('/api/session')
    .toPromise()
    .then( session =>
    {
      let user: UserService = session.json();

      this.setUser(user);
    })
    .catch( err =>
    {
      console.log( err );
    });
  }

  setUser(user: UserService)
  {
    if( user && user.id )
    {
      this.loggedIn = true;

      for( let prop in user )
      {
        this[prop] = user[prop];
      }

      this.gravatar.defaultAva = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000';

      // App-notification event "user is loggedIn"
      this.applicationRef.tick();
    }
  }

  redirectIfNoLoggedIn()
  {
    return this.initUser
    .then( () =>
    {
      if( !this.loggedIn )
      {
        this.router.navigate( ['pre-account/login'] );
      }
    })
    .catch( err =>
    {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

  logout()
  {
    this.http
    .delete('/api/session')
    .toPromise()
    .then( session =>
    {
      if( session && session.json().ok )
      {
        this.id = null;
        this.userEmail = null;
        this.userName = null;

        this.loggedIn = false;
      }

      // App-notification event "user is loggedOut"
      this.applicationRef.tick();
    })
    .catch( err =>
    {
      console.log( err.json() );
    });
  }
}
```

Now I can use this service as follows:

```ts
export class AccountModule
{
  constructor( private user: UserService)
  {
    user.redirectIfNoLoggedIn();
  }
}
```